# Azure AD SAML using Common Certificate instead of app specific

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, saml

So my observations and expectations is that when I configure an app for Single-Sign On, the certificate for that specific application will be used.

However I have some already registered applications that do not use these cert, but rather sign the assertion with one of the certificates from [Common Metadata](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml). **My question is: is there a way to configure this behaviour?** I have tried to mimic the configuration in a new app, but cannot get the same behaviour.

What I have have observed about the configuration of these apps:

- All these have at some point "talked to" ADFS - and have also used WS-FED (that is the goal here)
- Even if I try to access the app through MyApps, and there is 'nothing' answering, the signature will be with the common cert.
- I believe they all use App Proxy (With Azure AD pre-auth)
- They seem to have the Tags (8adf8e6e-67b2-4cf2-a259-e3dc5476c621, WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryGalleryApplicationNonPrimaryV1) which I do not get when I create a new SAML app.

This is what the assertion looks like:

```
<samlp:Response ID="RESPONSEID_REPLACED" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-10-11T17:47:30.259Z" Destination="https://127.0.0.1:444/applications/default.aspx" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://sts.windows.net/TENANT-ID-REPLACED/</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="ASSERTION_ID" IssueInstant="2021-10-11T17:47:30.243Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>https://sts.windows.net/TENANT-ID-REPLACED/</Issuer>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <Reference URI="#REFERENCE_URI_GUID_REPLACED">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <DigestValue>Zvoq+VZQsM+eW9HzHcYSJQvSm7L6E5urRYKQehkJf7w=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>LONG_SIGNATURE_REPLACED</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
                    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
```

Comment: which certificate you are talking about - Signing or Encryption? Signing cert is usually common for all RPs while the encryption cert is determined by respective RP during federation metadata exchange.

Comment: Added code as example. That signature is usually from the app-specific certificate, but in this case it shows a cert from the common metadata.

Comment: RP specific signing cert is used to verify the signature of the SAMLRequest sent by RP. It is not used for signing the SAMLResponse generated by ADFS. Common signing cert is used by ADFS for signing the SAMLResponse (assertion) for all the RPs. I think the behavior you are observing is as expected.

Comment: But it is not consistant. Some apps do this, some do not. ADFS is not necessarily a factor here... Azure is. The Response is sent from Azure and for some apps are signed with accounts.accesscontrol-cert and some with Azure AD Federated SSO-cert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug/weird situation. I had one detail wrong; it actually was using the Certificate that was on the enterprise application..

However, the default certificate on a newly created non-gallery or approxy-application will default to a public Azure Cert (Thumbprint `977B10FB9D1C087E3105564B1D31B09D247BEBCD`, subject `accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net`).

When you edit the configuration of SSO that certificate seems to be updated, but for some of my applications it seems not to have... So it was still signing with the default Azure AD certificate.